# I am trying to find out the id of the product sold month by month from 15 months of csv data and how many times it was sold in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, frequency

But there is a lot of duplicate codes when I do that way in bottom.

what should I do to avoid duplicate and do it in a shorter way?

[image of codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtxsO.png)

[output of codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY76R.png)

[here the data](https://dosya.co/oocz2391gm8b/train_purchases.csv.html)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


train_purchases = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Can\Desktop\dressipi_recsys2022\train_purchases.csv")


first_month = train_purchases.loc[(train_purchases['date'] > '2020-01-01') & (train_purchases['date'] <= '2020-01-31')].sort_values(by=["item_id"])["item_id"].tolist()

second_month = train_purchases.loc[(train_purchases['date'] > '2020-02-01') & (train_purchases['date'] <= '2020-02-31')].sort_values(by=["item_id"])["item_id"].tolist()

third_month = train_purchases.loc[(train_purchases['date'] > '2020-03-01') & (train_purchases['date'] <= '2020-03-31')].sort_values(by=["item_id"])["item_id"].tolist()

fourth_month = train_purchases.loc[(train_purchases['date'] > '2020-04-01') & (train_purchases['date'] <= '2020-04-31')].sort_values(by=["item_id"])["item_id"].tolist()

fifth_month = train_purchases.loc[(train_purchases['date'] > '2020-05-01') & (train_purchases['date'] <= '2020-05-31')].sort_values(by=["item_id"])["item_id"].tolist()

sixth_month = train_purchases.loc[(train_purchases['date'] > '2020-06-01') & (train_purchases['date'] <= '2020-06-31')].sort_values(by=["item_id"])["item_id"].tolist()



def most_frequent(List):
    counter = 0
    num = List[0] 
    for i in List:
        curr_frequency = List.count(i)
        if(curr_frequency> counter):
            counter = curr_frequency
            num = i
    print(num," id sold", List.count(num), "times. ")
    
    

most_frequent(first_month)
most_frequent(second_month)
most_frequent(third_month)
most_frequent(fourth_month)
most_frequent(fifth_month)
most_frequent(sixth_month)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
start = '2020-01-01'
end = '2021-03-31'
first_day = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='MS').astype(str).to_list() #get first day of month given range
end_day = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='M').strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59").astype(str).to_list() #get last day of month of given date
dates = dict(zip(first_day, end_day)) #convert lists to dictionary
#dates={'2020-01-01':'2020-01-31'}....

train_purchases['date']=pd.to_datetime(train_purchases['date'])
for k,v in dates.items():
    mask = train_purchases.loc[(train_purchases['date'] > k) & (train_purchases['date'] <= v)].sort_values(by=["item_id"]).item_id.value_counts()[:1]
    print(mask.index[0]," id sold", mask.iloc[0], "times. ")
'''
8060  id sold 564 times. 
8060  id sold 421 times. 
8060  id sold 375 times. 
8060  id sold 610 times. 
8060  id sold 277 times. 
8060  id sold 280 times. 
8622  id sold 290 times. 
8060  id sold 374 times. 
8060  id sold 638 times. 
8060  id sold 563 times. 
8060  id sold 1580 times. 
8060  id sold 765 times. 
19882  id sold 717 times. 
19882  id sold 570 times. 
19882  id sold 690 times.  

'''
```

Note

```
train_purchases['date'] > '2020-01-01'
```

If you use it as above, the first day of the month is not included in the calculation. If you want the first day of the month, you should use it as below

```
train_purchases['date'] >= '2020-01-01'
```

Comment: actually, it worked and wrote the data for 15 months, but according to the code I shared, the data for the first 6 months shows incomplete sales in some months. I'm not sure which one is correct, but could it be due to time factors in the date. [output_first_6_month](https://prnt.sc/uddNSfSE58q6)

Comment: Weird... There could be many reasons for this. Please add a sample of the data to the question. Also I suggest you check this little details as well. You used the greater than symbol for the first day, but this will not include the first day of the month in the calculation. And there are 29 days in February 2020 (this maybe not important)

Comment: and finally, can you run your method and the method in the answer again and compare them separately?

Comment: adding the data to question which I use. And  I replaced the function with yours it is calculate more faster now but still some months have different(less) repeated value according to the code in question.                                                                                                     #2020-04 my=610 - your=590
#2020-06 my=280 - your=274
#2020-09 my=638 - your=622
#2020-11 my=1580 - your=1451
#2021-02 my=570 - 533

Comment: Okey i edited answer. The date column you used first is of string type. First you have to convert it to datetime. Otherwise, the time filters will not work properly. Secondly, you don't need to use any function, you can use it in the question.

Comment: If you are going to use the first day of the month, you can get correct results if you change the filter you use from greater(**>**) to greater than equal(**>=**).

Comment: If you don't want to use the first day of the month, the outputs in my answer are correct.

Comment: Yeah I think u are right but when I copied your code and changing operator (train_purchases['date'] > k) to (train_purchases['date'] >= k) effect nothing. Interesting but still output same which is your.

Comment: Sorry i was talking about string date column. But since we converted the date column to datetime: `> 2020-01-01` actually means `>2020-01-01 00:00:00`. For example, we already get a row with date field `2020-01-01 00:00:01`. If you only look at the date(yyyy-mm--dd) basis, not the datetime, you should use greater equal (**>=**). I believe there is no problem now.

Comment: Yeah I get it but as I say above greater equal (train_purchases['date'] >= k) is not effect to output

Comment: yes, it does not affect the last version of the answer.

Comment: I added a change to end_date field.

Comment: Yes it's work now but fix your code which is strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59") add quotes(""). Thank you so much btw.  I am new about this data analyze things. Again I appreciate you.